# Using ContentCachingRequestWrapper causes Empty Parameters Map

Tags: java, spring, embedded-jetty

I have implemented a Filter, in which I want to read the content of request first for some checks and then I would like to go on.

But the problem is, that in the following filter from the filter chain the `getParameters()` Method from `class Request (org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request)` is called and not the `getParameters()` method from `class ContentCachingRequestWrapper`. So the `parametersMap` are not filled and is always empty.

Here is how my code looks like:

```
@Component
@Order(1)
public class EncodingFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

private static final Logger LOG = 
LoggerFactory.getLogger(EncodingFilter.class);

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, 
FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

final HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
HttpServletRequest servletRequest = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(req);

String read = ByteSource.wrap(ByteStreams.toByteArray(servletRequest.getInputStream()))
        .asCharSource(StandardCharsets.UTF_8).read();
// Doing analysis .....
// last step call filter chain
chain.doFilter(servletRequest, response);
}
}
```

And in Controller:

```
@PostMapping(
    value = Endpoints.Janus.INIT,
    produces = MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE
)
public ModelAndView controller(
    @RequestParam LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap<String> params,
    HttpServletRequest servletRequest
) {
 ....  
}
```

In the controller the params Map is always empty. 
If I don't call servletRequest.getInputStream() in my filter, the params Map is filled.

I am working with Spring Boot 1.5.6 with Jetty as Application Server

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`ContentCachingRequestWrapper` doesnt work that way and has some limitations. Only POST request and content type should be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as far as I remember. If this fits for you, here's what you should do:

```
final HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
HttpServletRequest servletRequest = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(req);
servletRequest.getParameterMap(); // needed for caching!!

String read = ByteSource.wrap(servletRequest.getContentAsByteArray())
    .asCharSource(StandardCharsets.UTF_8).read(); // Please note that we're not touching input stream!!
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thx a lot. This was the solution

Comment: @MichaelKronberger, please, accept this answer if it was helpful. Thanks in advance

Comment: Nicely explained! upvoting the answer!

Comment: Note: `multipart/form-data` is also relevant to `request.getParameter` calls **and** the multipart `request.getPart` methods.

Comment: What is ByteSource ?

Comment: Its from com.google.guava, add it in your pom.xml from Maven Repository to use ByteSource.

Comment: This answer looks ok, but not working as I do not know how to test from postman. I have encrypted data, and want to decrypt inside the interceptor. If I use radio button - application/x-www-form-urlencoded  it aske me key value pair. But I only know I was sending body. My controller looks like - public String saveData(@RequestBody String qWith,  @RequestAttribute("customAttribute") Book customAttribute) .. In the interceptor I was decypting and setting customattribute with decrypted value. How can I resolve my problem using www-form-urlencoded . I have to invoke this from Angular too

Comment: Perfect, you can't use ContentCachingRequestWrapper for application/json content type.

Comment: "Perfect, you can't use ContentCachingRequestWrapper for application/json content type" is there an alternative? Just code your own I assume?