# Required request body is missing after using ContentCachingRequestWrapper

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, filtering

I need to read the request payload in one of my `GenericFilterBean`.
Beacuse I cannot call [getreader twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7318632/java-lang-illegalstateexception-getreader-has-already-been-called-for-this-re) I used `ContentCachingRequestWrapper` like-

```
HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
ContentCachingRequestWrapper cachedRequest = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(httpRequest);
```

Getting the request body-

```
String payload = cachedRequest.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining());
```

And chaining the request-

```
chain.doFilter(cachedRequest, response);
```

But still my controller throws-

```
 .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by handler execution: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> com.siemens.plm.it.sf.api.controllers.OrderController.createCCOrder(com.siemens.plm.it.de.ms.provisioning.model.sap.SapQuoteCreationArgument,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) throws java.lang.Exception
```

How do I chain the request so I can read the payload in the controller as well?

Comment: With `ContentCachingRequestWrapper` you cannot read the body multiple times. In this tutorial there is an alternative, hope it helps. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-reading-httpservletrequest-multiple-times

Answer (score 7):

I faced same issue. You need to call getInputStream on requestWrapper in order to let it be cached. This is how your filter should look like:

```
@Component
public class CachingRequestBodyFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        ContentCachingRequestWrapper wrappedRequest = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper((HttpServletRequest) servletRequest);

        //this line is necessary to cache InputStream
        wrappedRequest.getInputStream();
        //String requestBody = IOUtils.toString(wrappedRequest.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8); with this line you can map requestBody to String


        chain.doFilter(wrappedRequest, servletResponse);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@PostMapping(ENDPOINT)
    void endpoint(HttpServletRequest request) {
        ContentCachingRequestWrapper requestWrapper = (ContentCachingRequestWrapper) request;
        String requestBody = new String(requestWrapper.getContentAsByteArray());
        //process requestBody
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In general you can go with Krzysztof's approach, which is the one that is shown is all websites/tutorials.

But I'd like to continue receiving the `@RequestBody` directly in the WebResource/RestController. For that, this approach won't work because internally Spring doesn't call `getContentAsByteArray()`.

So, here is an alternative way:

For the `@RequestBody` Spring uses the method `read()` from the InputStream. So we need to override that one. To do that, we'll have to create new wrappers. Sample in Kt:

```
class RequestBodyContentWrapper(private val wrapped: ContentCachingRequestWrapper) : ContentCachingRequestWrapper(wrapped) {

    private val bodyProcessorIS: RequestBodyInputStreamWrapper by lazy {
        RequestBodyInputStreamWrapper(super.getInputStream())
    }

    override fun getInputStream(): ServletInputStream {
        return bodyProcessorIS
    }

    // use the method supported by ContentCachingRequestWrapper to read the bytes
    fun prepareInputStream() = bodyProcessorIS.resetReading(wrapped.contentAsByteArray)
}

class RequestBodyInputStreamWrapper(private val wrapped: ServletInputStream) : ServletInputStream() {

    private lateinit var bais: ByteArrayInputStream

    // convert the bytes read from the cache to InputStream 
    // which later can be used in the read()
    fun resetReading(bytes: ByteArray) {
        this.bais = ByteArrayInputStream(bytes)
    }

    override fun read() = bais.read()

    override fun isFinished() = wrapped.isFinished

    override fun isReady(): Boolean = wrapped.isReady

    override fun setReadListener(readListener: ReadListener?) = wrapped.setReadListener(readListener)

}
```

Then, in the filter:

```
override fun doFilterInternal(originalRequest: HttpServletRequest, response: HttpServletResponse, filterChain: FilterChain) {
        val contentRequest = ContentCachingRequestWrapper(originalRequest)

        val hmac = ...
        // ... internal logic

        val readableRequest = RequestBodyContentWrapper(contentRequest)
        readableRequest.prepareInputStream()
        filterChain.doFilter(readableRequest, response)
    }
```

That's needed because Spring internal classes won't use `getContentAsByteArray` but `inputStream.read()`.  And it's disappointing that Spring's ContentCachingRequestWrapper doesn't handle that (doesn't allow to use `read()` later).

It might be not so straightforward at first, but worked for me. Take some time to understand it.
I prefer this way in order to keep the RestControllers cleaner. The filter usually will be unique (that is, this additional logic is in a single place); as opposed to RestController, which we often have many.

Answer (score -1):

I think by doing this :

```
String payload = cachedRequest.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining());
```

you are doing it wrong.

Try this :

```
String input = ByteSource.wrap(cachedRequest.getContentAsByteArray())
    .asCharSource(StandardCharsets.UTF_8).read();
```

As the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/ContentCachingRequestWrapper.html) suggests:

> caches all content read from the input stream and reader, and allows this content to be retrieved via a byte array

Some helpful links:
[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49250367/using-contentcachingrequestwrapper-causes-empty-parameters-map), [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49250367/using-contentcachingrequestwrapper-causes-empty-parameters-map).

Comment: I have exactly the same issue and the comment from @Furquam Ahmed is not workung.

Comment: Results in an empty string for me

Comment: This answer suggests it cannot be used for application/json request types https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49250367/using-contentcachingrequestwrapper-causes-empty-parameters-map is there another way?